# How Can I Change LabelFrame position from righit side to the bottom in HORIZONTAL shape

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, ttk

```
root = Tk()
centerRoot()
root.state('zoomed') 
root.title('sample data')

# Menu Configuration
menubar = Menu(root, background='#E4FDE1', foreground='blue', activebackground='white', activeforeground='black',font="myFont")
tab1 = Menu(root,tearoff=0, background='#E4FDE1', foreground='blue', activebackground='white', activeforeground='black',font="myFont")  
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=tab1)  
tab2 = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0,background='#E4FDE1', foreground='blue', activebackground='white', activeforeground='black',font="myFont") 
menubar.add_cascade(label="Tools" , menu=tab2)   



frame1 = LabelFrame(root, text="pKa")
frame1.pack(side=LEFT,fill="both", expand=False,padx=5,pady=5)

frame2 = LabelFrame(root, text="%")
frame2.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=BOTH,padx=5,pady=5)

frame3 = LabelFrame(root, text="RPM")
frame3.pack(side='left', expand=False, fill=BOTH,padx=5,pady=5)

ttk.Separator(
    frame1,
    orient=VERTICAL,
).pack(fill='none', expand=False)

ttk.Separator(
    frame2,
    orient=VERTICAL,
).pack(fill='none', expand=True)

ttk.Separator(
    frame3,
    orient=HORIZONTAL
).pack(fill='none', expand=True)
root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

How Can I move Frame3 Right of the screen to the bottom in HORIZONTAL shape with pack() method ?
Exactly under the Fram2 .
what should I do ? please help me
thank you

Comment: Pleae make sure the code is runnable, and that it's a [mcve]. For example, this calls an undefined function `centerRoot`, and the menubar doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it on the bottom, tell `pack` that you want it on the bottom. Also, because the order that you call `pack` matters, pack it before you pack the other frames.

I find that fixing layout issues is usually much easier when you put all calls to `pack` together, grouped by their parent, like in the following example:

```
frame3.pack(side=BOTTOM, expand=False, fill=BOTH,padx=5,pady=5)
frame1.pack(side=LEFT,fill="both", expand=False,padx=5,pady=5)
frame2.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=BOTH,padx=5,pady=5)
```

For the canonical description of how the packer works, see [The packer algorithm](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/pack.htm#M27) in the official tcl/tk manual pages.

Answer (score 0):

> How Can I move Frame3 Right of the screen to the bottom in HORIZONTAL
> shape with pack() method ? Exactly under the Fram2

Comment out `frame1.pack(...)`, `frame2.pack(...)` and `frame2.pack(...)`.

Arrange location:

```
frame1.pack(side=LEFT,fill="both", expand=False,padx=5,pady=5)
frame3.pack(side=BOTTOM, expand=False, fill=BOTH,padx=5,pady=5) #<= under frame2
frame2.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=BOTH,padx=5,pady=5)
```

Screenshot: **Exactly under the Fram2**.

[image]

Looking at Bryan Oakley's answer.

screenshot: **Not exactly** under the Fram2.

[image]